# In "All valid data bits", what does "valid" refer to?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> Coding of NVB (Number of Valid Bits)
>
> Length: 1 byte
>
> The upper 4 bits are called “Byte count” and specify the integer part of the **number of all valid data bits transmitted by the PCD** (including SEL and NVB) divided by 8. Consequently, the minimum value of “Byte count” is 2 and the maximum value is 7.

What does the bold text mean?

1. Number of all the bits in a valid-data transmission?
2. Number of all the valid-bits in a data transmission?

I mean how can I understand what is the reference of *valid* (data or bits)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, when you have a noun with a number of attributives (which may include nouns used attributively), the head noun is the last one in the construction, and all attributes refer to that head noun.

> a yellow school bus

It is a *bus* we are talking about. It is *yellow*, and it goes to *school*.
If there is such a thing as a *yellow school*, we would probably still not read this phrase as referring to a *bus* that goes to a *yellow school*.

If the attributes should refer to each other, we would have to make that clear by somehow connecting them. Sometimes we can leave out the space, sometimes we can use a hyphen. Compare these phrases:

> a high school bus, a yellow school bus
>   a highschool bus, a yellow-school bus

The *intuitive* way of reading *valid data bits* is:

> valid bits + data bits -> valid data bits.

If the author would mean:

> valid data + data bits

He could opt for:

> valid-data bits

or, and that would certainly avoid confusion:

> bits of valid data

Answer (score 1):

According to the paragraph title, it's the second one, the number of *valid bits of data*.

Comment: If there wasn't any title, how could I understand the meaning?

Comment: _Coding of NVB (Number of Valid Bits)_

Comment: Yes,you are right. But I said, assume that I didn't quoted the first line ( _Coding of NVB (Number of Valid Bits)_ ). In the that case how can we understand the meaning?